# Rspec: Testing registarion routing in rails with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I'm Trying to build a simple Blog using rails 4 and  For authentication I'm using Devise.

The blog is simple and it will only have one registered user which is the admin. so the registration page should be available when there are no users in the database else it will redirect to the home page. 
I'm trying to learn testing in the process. So I started testing the `RegistrationContrroler` However it doesn't seem to pass.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController       

  before_action :one_user_registered?, only: [:new, :create]

  protected

  def one_user_registered?
    if ((User.count == 1) & (user_signed_in?))
      redirect_to root_path
    elsif User.count == 1
      redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
  end

end
```

Specs:

```
RSpec.describe RegistrationsController, type: :controller do

  context "Admin already registred" do
    it "cannot create new user" do
      @user_attr = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user)
      # Create Admin
      User.create!(@user_attr)
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      post :create, user: @user_attr
      User.count should eq_to(1)

    end
  end
end
```

`spec/factories.rb` :

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "user#{n}@example.com" }
    password "secure"
  end

  factory :post do
    sequence(:id){ |n| n }
    sequence(:title) { |n| "Post title #{n}" }
    body "Post body"
    sequence(:slug) { |n| "Post title #{n}" }
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }

  authenticated :user do
    resources :posts
  end

  unauthenticated :user do
       resources :posts, only: [:show, :index]
  end

  root 'posts#index' 
end
```

Stacktrace :

```
F

Failures:

  1) RegistrationsController Admin already registred cannot create new user
     Failure/Error: User.count should eq_to(1)

       expected: 1
            got: #<RegistrationsController:0x00000003a413b8 @_action_has_layout=true, @_routes=nil, @_headers={"Conten...enticatable]>, @req touest_format=:html, @marked_for_same_origin_verification=false, @current_user=nil>

       (compared using ==)
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-support-3.5.0/lib/rspec/support.rb:87:in `block in <module:Support>'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-support-3.5.0/lib/rspec/support.rb:96:in `notify_failure'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-expectations-3.5.0/lib/rspec/expectations/fail_with.rb:27:in `fail_with'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-expectations-3.5.0/lib/rspec/expectations/handler.rb:38:in `handle_failure'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-expectations-3.5.0/lib/rspec/expectations/handler.rb:50:in `block in handle_matcher'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-expectations-3.5.0/lib/rspec/expectations/handler.rb:27:in `with_matcher'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-expectations-3.5.0/lib/rspec/expectations/handler.rb:48:in `handle_matcher'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/memoized_helpers.rb:81:in `should'
     # ./spec/controllers/registrations_controller_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:252:in `instance_exec'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:252:in `block in run'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:494:in `block in with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:451:in `block in with_around_example_hooks'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:471:in `block in run'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:611:in `block in run_around_example_hooks_for'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:336:in `call'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-rails-3.5.1/lib/rspec/rails/example/controller_example_group.rb:191:in `block (2 levels) in <module:ControllerExampleGroup>'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:441:in `instance_exec'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:441:in `instance_exec'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:382:in `execute_with'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:613:in `block (2 levels) in run_around_example_hooks_for'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:336:in `call'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-rails-3.5.1/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:127:in `block (2 levels) in <module:MinitestLifecycleAdapter>'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:441:in `instance_exec'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:441:in `instance_exec'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:382:in `execute_with'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:613:in `block (2 levels) in run_around_example_hooks_for'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:336:in `call'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:614:in `run_around_example_hooks_for'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:471:in `run'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:451:in `with_around_example_hooks'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:494:in `with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:249:in `run'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:627:in `block in run_examples'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:623:in `map'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:623:in `run_examples'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:589:in `run'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:590:in `block in run'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:590:in `map'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:590:in `run'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:113:in `block (3 levels) in run_specs'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:113:in `map'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:113:in `block (2 levels) in run_specs'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1836:in `with_suite_hooks'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:112:in `block in run_specs'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:77:in `report'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:111:in `run_specs'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:87:in `run'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in `run'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.5.1/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
     # /home/chaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'

Finished in 0.08188 seconds (files took 1.95 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/registrations_controller_spec.rb:7 # RegistrationsController Admin already registred cannot create new user
```

Comment: `((User.count == 1) & (user_signed_in?))` this should be   `(User.count == 1 && user_signed_in?)`

Comment: @PardeepDhingra That doesn't make a difference as far as I know. It's not a problem of precedence.

Comment: @PardeepDhingra is right, though... `&` is incorrect, `&&` is correct.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn Indeed even though it works well since bitwise and logic operator works the same in ruby. https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide/issues/300

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a dot!

```
User.count.should eq_to(1)
```

Adding a `should` method is the way rspec patches all objects to support the `should` comparisons.

Preferable would be...

```
expect(User.count).to eq(1)
```

The error showed that the `should` by itself was received by the `RegistrationsController`, not by the `User.count`... and of course the RegistrationsController doesn't equal 1.